# Can an android phone act both as a client and server?

Tags: android, file, system, distributed

I want to implement a distributed file system. So, can an android act both as a client and a server?

Comment: Obviously Android can easily act as a client for downloading files and I should imagine you could implement something for serving up files but it wouldn't be recommended because of battery/network considerations.

Comment: Actually, I am unable to figure how to identify an android device uniquely on the network. Suppose, if I want to transfer 'filea' from 'Android-A' to 'Android-B' , then how can I identify the 'Android-B' if I don't know the ip-address of the device. Could you please tell me how can I do this? Because for wireless devices, I assume that the ip address is not same all the time.

Comment: Messy method: have MAC addresses or something similar stored in a database on a server that both devices can access. Actually, that's probably a bad idea.